# How do I install the latest Magento 2 via composer with sample data and Elasticsearch?

Tags: magento2, composer, elasticsearch

Using  Debian 10, I installed PHP 7.4, PHP-FPM 7.4, Mysql 8, NGINX, Elasticsearch, Magento2 via composer, Redis-Server, varnish, Changed the ownership of all files to a user, and run NGINX using this user, Configured PHPMyAdmin. Is any tutorial available to make the server works properly?

Answer (score 0):

**Magento installation** via composer is easy and fast. To install magento via composer follow these commands:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.3 . --prefer-dist --no-interaction --dev
```

After complete these commands, all magento sources was copied to your magento2 directory and you can run installation using CLI

```
bin/magento: php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost.com" --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name=<db_name> --db-user=<db_user> --db-password=<db_password> --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin" --admin-email="<your_email>" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="<your_password>" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

**NOTE:** Replace the URL and database details with your original detail here.

**Install Sample Data**
After magento 2 installation via composer, sample data installation is easy:

```
php bin/magneto sampledata:deploy

php bin/magento module:enable --all

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Using docker is best solution. Use docker image bitnami, it comes all the server setup needed for magento latest version including latest magento installation. They update the docker image regularly so you can update the newer one also.

Before that you should know how to use docker.

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Bitnami image
https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/magento

There are other docker images also. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you taking a look at:
https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento

It has very nice [free] video tutorials and setting up a Magento development with all your needs is super easy.

Answer (score 0):

After you've downloaded Magento with composer, You can use below setup script to install Magento latest version with elasticsearch

> bin/magento setup:install 
> --base-url=http://magento.local 
> --db-host=localhost 
> --db-name=local.magento 
> --db-user=magento 
> --db-password=magento 
> --admin-firstname=admin 
> --admin-lastname=admin 
> --admin-email=info@admin.com 
> --admin-user=admin 
> --admin-password=admin123 
> --language=en_US 
> --currency=USD 
> --timezone=America/Chicago 
> --use-rewrites=1 
> --search-engine=elasticsearch7 
> --elasticsearch-host=localhost 
> --elasticsearch-port=9200 
> --elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 
> --elasticsearch-timeout=15